# Intellij IDEA Ruby Language Level

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

I got a Rails Project in intellij idea but somehow the language level seems to be set on 1.8. I got the following configuration:

[image]

[image]

But it still shows the following error:

[image]

Am I missing something? When I had problems with the colon syntax before, it was always the language level.

Thanks,
Robin

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what the problem exactly was but I guess it had something todo with binstubs. What I did:

1. I opened the project in RubyMine, where I got the warning: "no ruby interpreter configured for the project", though the correct rvm ruby was selected
2. I deleted the `.idea` folder and the `bin` folder
3. I opened the project in RubyMine again, this time it correctly recognised the rvm ruby
4. I opened the project in Intellij IDEA, everything works fine here too.

Comment: I just had the problem with Intellij idea again, setting language level didn't work, neither did reopening the project. What did work was not opening the project via "Open" but removing the .idea folder and choosing "Import" at the Intellij IDEA startup screen.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given by rweng:

1. Remove .idea folder
2. File/New/ProjectFromExistingSources

Maybe deleting the module and recreating the same might also help